# Regular Expression to Replace All But One Character In String

Tags: java, regex

I need regular expression to replace all matching characters except the first one in a squence in string.

For example;

For matching with 'A' and replacing with 'B'

- 'AAA' should be replaced with 'ABB'
- 'AAA AAA' should be replaced with 'ABB ABB'

For matching with ' ' and replacing with 'X'

- '[space][space][space]A[space][space][space]' should be replaced with '[space]XXA[space]XX'

Comment: The first character of the string, or the first matching character?

Comment: @jcaron Yes the first matching character in a sequence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use this regex for replacement:

```
\\BA
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/qC7pS4)

- `\B` (between word characters) assert position where `\b` (word boundary) doesn't match
- `A` matches the character `A` literally

**Java Code:**

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("\\BA", "B");
```

---

**UPDATE** For second part of your question use this regex for replacement:

```
"(?<!^|\\w) "
```

**Code:**

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("(?<!^|\\w) ", "X");
```

#### [Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/aK6pG1)

Comment: It's working fine for most of cases except for spaces. Any suggestion?

Comment: Give me a sample value for which it doesn't work and I will tweak it.

Comment: `' ABC '` should be replaced with `' --ABC --'` that appears to be totally new requirement. Can you clarify it?

Comment: It's not working for multiple spaces in a sequence, when space it to be replaced with some other character.

Comment: Actually I added 3 spaces before and after 'ABC' in the mentioned example, but editor replaced all with one space.

Comment: Right but **replacing spaces with hyphens** was not even in first few edits or I missed it?

Comment: @anubhava You are right. In start, I didn't mentioned spaces in a sequence explicitly.

Comment: So you want all spaces to be converted to hyphens or there is some logic for this replacement? Can you edit the question to show sample input and expected output for this case.

Comment: @anubhava All spaces except first one in a sequence. Edited question with example.

Answer (score 4):

**Negative Lookbehind and Beginning of String Anchor**

Use the regex `(?<!^| )A` like this:

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?<!^| )A", "B");
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/aQ9eY8), inspect the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

- `(?<!^| )` asserts that what immediately precedes the position is neither the beginning of the string nor a space character
- `A` matches `A`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: FYI, added explanation and demo. :)

Comment: I edited the regex, demo and explanation, Ammar, please have a look. :)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, that would have worked too. But I really like to treat lookbehinds as "a real person", you know what I mean? Give it some meat, like for this C# regex we had earlier.

Comment: Ammar, if you want to have more rules, for instance it can happen after several spaces... You just keep changing the simple lookbehind, and adding ORs if needed. For instance, `(?<!^|[ ]*)` if you can have multiple spaces before the first `A`, and `(?<!^|[ ]*|[@_])` if you also don't want to replace the first `A` after a `@` or `_`... It's a very very flexible method, you can keep expanding it.